# Return value from WCF without waiting for internal processes

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way to return a value back to the client whilst still letting a long running process to continue executing?

I want to return a value to the user who calls the WCF service method. Without waiting for the processes within the service to complete. I basically make a call to a database procedure which does stuff, and sends communication back to the client using another means and I want to beat these communications with my own return value.

Is this possible, can I spawn a new thread or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Write another method, return the result, call the service again for the long running operation?

Comment: Try a duplex service, as posted [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF). Your method call will invoke the long-running action. Another callback method will then be invoked by the server, returning the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)